# $R=\{ (a,b)\in A\times A\mid{}$ for every $X\subseteq A\smallsetminus\{a,b\}$, if $X \cup \{a\} \in F$ then $X\cup \{b\}\in F\} $ is transitive.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations, proof-explanation

I am stuck on the following problem and still haven't the slightest clue how to proceed with the partial solution...

> Suppose $A$ is a set, and $F\subseteq P(A)$, where $P(A)$ is a powerset. Let $R=\{ (a,b)\in A\times A\mid \text{ for every } X\subseteq A\smallsetminus \{a,b\}, \text{ if } X \cup \{a\} \in F \text{ then } X\cup \{b\}\in F\}$. Show that $R$ is transitive.
>
> Partial solution: Suppose $aRb$ and $bRc$. To prove $aRc$, suppose that $X\subseteq A \smallsetminus \{a,c\}$ and $X\cup \{a\} \in F$; we must prove $X\cup \{c\} \in F$. To do this, you may find it helpful to consider two cases: $b\notin X$ or $b\in X$. In the latter case, work with the sets $X'=(X\cup\{a\}) \smallsetminus \{b\}  $ and $X''=(X\cup \{c\})\smallsetminus\{b\}$.

I have no idea where $X'$ and $X''$ are from, e.g. are they assumptions or did I need to derive them? So I don't really know what kind of inference am I allowed to work on them. Even if I take them as assumptions, with the handful few things I have no idea what can I do with them. Frankly, the whole partial solution (apart from the givens and goal explanation) did more to confuse me than to help me.

If I apply $b\notin X$ to $X'$, I would even (seemingly mistakenly) get $b\in \{a\}$, which must mean $b=a$, which has gotta be wrong.

The only thing I can work out is this: by instantiating $X\subseteq A \smallsetminus \{a,c\}$, we get $b \in X \subseteq A$. So it follows that $b\in A$ - but this is already given in the definition of $R$.

I know I am supposed to have tried myself before asking; but I have been struggling with this for two weeks and still have no clue. Could anyone please help?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Note that $\cup$ is normally used in things like $A\cup B$ and $A_1\cup\cdots\cup A_n$, and $\bigcup$ is normally used in things like $\displaystyle\bigcup_{k=1}^n A_k.$  I edited accordingly (and did lots of other MathJax improvements). $\qquad$

Comment: Thank you! Will be mindful of them in the future

Answer (score 2):

HINT: When $b\notin X$ there is no reason to consider $X'$ and $X''$; that case goes through very directly.

Suppose that $b\notin X$. Then $X\subseteq A\setminus\{a,b\}$, $X\cup\{a\}\in F$, and $a\mathrel{R}b$, so $X\cup\{b\}\in F$. Moreover, $X\subseteq A\setminus\{b,c\}$ (why?), and $b\mathrel{R}c$, so $X\cup\{c\}\in F$, which is exactly what we wanted.

It’s when $b\in X$ that we have to be a little cleverer: in that case we don’t have $X\subseteq A\setminus\{a,b\}$, so we can’t directly use the fact that $a\mathrel{R}b$. The hint suggests that we consider the sets

$$X'=(X\cup\{a\})\setminus\{b\}$$

and

$$X''=(X\cup\{c\})\setminus\{b\}$$

that are obtained by removing $b$ from $X$ and replacing it with $a$ and $c$, respectively. We know that $X\subseteq A\setminus\{a,c\}$.

- Verify that $X'\subseteq A\setminus\{b,c\}$ and $X''\subseteq A\setminus\{a,b\}$.
- Show further that $X\cup\{a\}=X'\cup\{b\}$, $X'\cup\{c\}=X''\cup\{a\}$, and $X\cup\{c\}=X''\cup\{b\}$.

Now $b\mathrel{R}c$, and $X'\cup\{b\}=X\cup\{a\}\in F$, so $X'\cup\{c\}\in F$. And $X'\cup\{c\}=X''\cup\{a\}$, so $X''\cup\{a\}\in F$.

- Show that $X''\cup\{b\}\in F$, and conclude that $X\cup\{c\}\in F$, as desired.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help Prof! But how did you get $X\subseteq A\smallsetminus \{a,b\}$? I know we have $X\subseteq A$, which is given, but what about the $\smallsetminus \{a,b\}$?

In fact this has been where I got stuck; I knew I somehow gotta utilise the transitive relation. But I simply can't kickstart it since I can't think of how to get the said component above...

Comment: @Daniel: You’re welcome! You’re starting with an $X\subseteq A\setminus\{a,c\}$, so you know that $a\notin X$. Thus, in the case $b\notin X$ you immediately have $X\subseteq A\setminus\{a,b\}$, because you know that neither $a$ nor $b$ is in $X$.

Comment: I am terribly sorry but I am still rather confused...I don't understand how can we get $a\notin X$ from $X\subseteq A\smallsetminus \{a,c\}$. To me this set just refers to everything that is in $A$ if it is in $X$, and is neither $a$ or $c$ (because of the set minus).

Comment: @Daniel: You just said it yourself: $X$ contains only things that are in $A$ ***and are not*** $a$ or $c$. In particular, nothing in $X$ can be $a$, so $a\notin X$.

Comment: But why a subset instead of conjunction? I would have thought that it should be $X\smallsetminus\{a,c\}$?

And if we instantiate $X\subseteq A\smallsetminus \{a,c\}$ to $a$, wouldn't we get $a\in \{a,c\}$, which surely is contradictory?

Thank you so much!!

Comment: @Daniel: I think that you’re somehow making it much harder than it really is. You have a set $X$ that by hypothesis is a subset of $A\setminus\{a,c\}$; that’s your starting point. The object $a$ is clearly not an element of the set $A\setminus\{a,c\}$, so it cannot possibly belong to $X$. Neither can $c$, for the same reason. $X$ could conceivably contain any other element of $A$, but by hypothesis it absolutely cannot contain $a$ or $c$. Therefore we know for sure that $a\notin X$ and $c\notin X$.

Comment: Oh I get it now!! I thought that $X$ is a subset of $A$, instead of $A\smallsetminus\{a,c\}$ (i.e. I thought this was $\forall x((x\in X\to x\in A)\land  x\notin\{a,c\})$. I must have some misunderstanding about the scope of the subset sign.

Comment: But I am still very confused and have a lot of questions...would you mind if I ask about those too? Thank you so, so much and sorry for being so annoying!

Comment: For $X'\subseteq A\smallsetminus\{b,c\}$, I am assuming $x\in X$ and $x\in \{a\}$ in turn from $X'$. If I assume $x\in X$, I can prove it alright. But if I assume $x\in \{a\}$, that means $x=a$. But we can only get $x\notin \{b,c\}$ if we know that $a\neq b$ and $a\neq c$ right? And how can I get $x\in A$?

Comment: And for $X\cup \{a\}=X'\cup\{b\}$, for the $\to$, I am again assuming $x\in X$ and $x\in \{a\}$ in turn, but it seems that it is impossible to get $x\notin \{b\}$ (from $X'$) with either of them...
Likewise, for $\leftarrow$, assuming $x\in \{b\}$ seems to be a complete deadend and cannot get me $x\in X$ or $x\in \{a\}$...

Comment: And with regards to $X$ and $X'$, I have never seen operations like that (removing and replacing sets at will) before; is it legitimate for us to create these sets simply because they can be defined with the materials we have at hand? Because without knowing how they come to be I don't really see how they help us in the overall proof...

Comment: @Daniel: The set operations like set difference, union, and intersection all take precedence over the subset/inclusion relations. And yes, we can apply any of the standard set operations to sets that we already have in order to make new sets. I’m in the midst of a few things at the moment, but I’ll come back to the specific questions in a bit.

Comment: Thank you so much Prof! Please just answer whenever you are free, as I did (annoyingly) ask a lot there; I am happy as it is that someone is helping me out

Comment: @Daniel: You know that $X\subseteq A$ and $a\in A$, so $$X'=(X\cup\{a\})\setminus\{b\}\subseteq X\cup\{a\}\subseteq A\;.$$ We already know that $X\subseteq A\setminus\{b,c\}$, so in particular $b,c\notin X$, and therefore $a,b,c\notin X\setminus\{a\}$. Adding $b$ to the set $X\setminus\{a\}$ doesn’t add $a$ or $c$, so $a,c\notin X'$, and therefore $X'\subseteq A\setminus\{a,c\}$. I am assuming here that $b$ is different from both $a$ and $c$, because the result is trivial if $b=a$ or $b=c$. \\ For $X\cup\{a\}=X'\cup\{b\}$ it may help to realize that $X'$ is obtained from $X$ simply by ...

Comment: ... replacing $b$ with $a$; everything else remains the same.